# Why is my Contact Form 7 creating a huge white space underneath the form?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

In creating my website, i used a contact form with the Contact Form 7 plugin. However, when placing this in the website, it creates a huge white space underneath and pushes the other items down.

Code like padding-bottom doesn't work in this situation.

Is there a way to fix this with only css?

```
.wpcf7-form p {
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please check contact form div and class structure.
may be there are any css added so you can change HTML via form tab http://prntscr.com/n91u20 and apply important css on it.

Still any issue then can you please explain more with screenshot.
Possible share site url so I can check more.

Comment: I used the next structure: https://snag.gy/bsrWQq.jpg , however the added height doesn't add anything. But besides that I see nothing that could cause it.

Comment: can you please provide front site screenshot where you added contact form 7 shortcode or possible share page URL so I can get better idea about issue and I can give proper solution for it.

Comment: You need to apply min-height as auto instead of 587px on fusion-column-wrapper class css.

check screenshot as well http://prntscr.com/n9x8xw http://prntscr.com/n9xc0y
Hope now you will get solution

Comment: Please let me know answer is helpful or not

Comment: so still issue not solved in contact form? I checked site and I think now issue is fixed.  can you please give feedback of my answer if possible